# Redefine basic types in C++

Tags: c++, typedef

Is it possible to redefine what an `int` is in C++?

The reason is because I want to simulate some Arduino code on a computer, *without* changing the Arduino code. For example to demonstrate overflow the same way, `int` would need to be 16-bits instead of the 32-bits it is on my machine.

So essentially I want to:

```
typedef int16_t int;
```

As well as doing the same for other data types that Arduino uses.

However I don't think that is possible, as it throws the error (unsurprisingly):

```
error: cannot combine with previous 'type-name' declaration specifier
```

Is there a way I can do this easily?

Comment: probably the only way to do it without touching the code is with a compiler switch. Not sure which one but the gcc docs should list it if it exists.

Comment: You could do something crazy like `#define int int16_t`

Comment: @VadaPoché Defining a macro named after a keyword exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: It looks like that actually works, but it breaks a *lot* of things, haha. 

Looks like I would need to confine that change to the Arduino portion of the code. I will investigate. Thank you!

Comment: @IgorTandetnik which is why I said it's "crazy" as a warning.

Comment: @areth Of course yes. You'll have to confine it to the Arduino portion of the code. :-)

Comment: Write your arduino code using fixed-width types, then this problem won't exist.  Unless there is a specific arduino-emulator for PC that you can compile to,  writing portable code is your best bet and there is always the possibility that something may differ due to architectural differences between the two systems.

Comment: Remember, there's a whole standard library which already has an idea what `int` is, and that's compiled in. You might need to recompile the standard library. Now, in this age, with open-source implementations, this isn't _impossible_, but the way you phrase your question suggests that you wouldn't know how.

Answer (score 2):

You can't redefine `int` but you *can* stop writing code in terms of `int` and use a type alias like:

```
typedef int int_type;

int main()
{
    int_type i = 0;

    // etc...
}
```

Then you can switch type when you want:

```
typedef int16_t int_type; // now using 16 bit integers
```