# Is it a good idea to typedef int32_t as int?

Tags: c++

Is it a good idea to redefine types like `int16_t`, `int32_t` as `short` and `int` respectively?

I prefer to work with fixed width integer types but I like the simplicity of `short`, `int` etc.

Comment: I'd expect compilers to scream living hell. Did you try?

Comment: No you cant redefine types in C++ but you can set aliases, which is what typedef is used for. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42944203/9172668) answer

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types short must be at least 16 bit

Comment: Doing this would result in confusion. Some other poor sod reads your code, sees `int`, knows `int` on platform X is 64 bit, and then makes assumptions that are utterly wrong because you've aliased `int32_t`. Bugs will ensue.

Comment: @Renat my bad, i meant 16 for short

Comment: You could `static_assert` in your code where you explicitely need a certain size

Comment: @Yunnosch gcc compiled without any problems

Comment: `int`,`short` etc. are keywords and cannot be redefined with `typedef`.

Comment: If you want shorter names, why not simply `typedef int32_t i32; typedef uint16_t u16;`?

Comment: @Aconcagua not just shorter names, but familiar names ;)

Comment: I've seen quite a number of systems having int only 16 bit wide. What would you do on these??? Why do you think those (u)int*N*_t arose?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is a bad idea because it violates the [principle of least surprise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

Your application may also be not binary compatible with APIs using built-in `int` and `short`.

However, built-in types cannot be redefined and that is a good thing.

You can still come up with shorter type names though:

```
namespace my_short_types {

using u16 = uint16_t;
using u32 = uint32_t;

} // my_short_types

using namespace my_short_types;
using my_short_types::u32; // When there is ambiguity with BSD types.
```